# send email with attachment after the file was saved - excel

Tags: excel, email-attachments

I am trying to send an email with the attached file after it was saved with new data.
The file is saved on a shared network folder, and it seems that the problem is it takes too long for the save and the file attached in the email contains the previously saved data.
If i use the file locally, the attached file is ok, contains the new data.

I don't need to do anything else with the file after the data was updated. Just complete new data save and close the file.
Is there a way for the procedure to wait until the file is actually saved so it will send the updated one?

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call Send_Email_with_Attachment

End Sub



Sub Send_Email_with_Attachment()

Dim MyOutlook As Object
Set MyOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim MyMail As Object
Set MyMail = MyOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

MyMail.To = "example@email.com"
MyMail.Subject = "Updated data"
MyMail.Body = "File was update" & " on " & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy") & " at " & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "You can find the file here:  \\network\data\!Daily "

Attached_File = "\\network\data\!Daily\11_Daily_Dashboard.xlsm"
MyMail.Attachments.Add Attached_File

MyMail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, someone please correct me if not... but if you save and this causes the script to run, then maybe it completes the script before actually saving??? You could check the file date time before sending the email: https://exceloffthegrid.com/obtaining-the-save-status-of-a-file-using-vba/

Comment: Hi, i think that is exactly the issue. Maybe the solution is a loop that compares last save date with current date, and only if last_save >= curr_date then send the email. Problem is i have little experience with VBA and not sure how to write that

Comment: You could add code to save a copy of the workbook, email that copy then delete the copy, but this does seem like a long winded solution. so the code could create the saved copy, then create a loop: for i = 1 to 10  - check file exists if it does end the loop and proceed to email - if not then wait so many milliseconds and then start the loop again with:   Next i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries with no luck, kept getting error messages after 2-3 times when it worked, managed to get it working with no errors by writing this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

CreateObject("Excel.Application").Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

Call Send_Email_with_Attachment

End Sub
```

Then the rest of code from original post:

```
Sub Send_Email_with_Attachment()

Dim MyOutlook As Object
Set MyOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
' rest of code from original post goes here
```

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution. You can accept your own answer, this way anyone who finds this post will see the working solution. Here's a link on how to accept your own answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer